# How to make fonts smooth and readable in Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, fonts, xorg

**What is the best, most foolproof way of getting nice font rendering in Linux?**

Currently, I am experiencing thin, ugly fonts (shown below). I have wasted too much time tweaking `fonts.conf`, and I have yet to find a decent combination.

I am running Debian 6.0 with no desktop environment (just Openbox for a window manager) in a VM on a Macbook Pro (OS X 10.7.4).

### Screenshots

The following screenshots were taken without `fonts.conf` and `.Xdefaults` tweaks.

- running in "native" Openbox environment:

  [image: running in "native" Openbox environment]
- running over X11, which looks a little worse than Openbox:

  [image: running over X11, which looks a little worse than Openbox]

Comment: And this is what I would like to achieve: [Emacs on OS X screenshot](https://github.com/jmdeldin/ir-black-theme.el/raw/master/screenshot.png)

Comment: Note to readers: Since N.N.s edit the screenshots are shown inline but are also scaled, so the difference in rendering might not be visible. Open the images in a new tab to view them unscaled. You might also want to zoom in (without interpolation) to clearly see the difference (hinting, subpixel rendering)

Comment: Did you ever get rendering to look as good as the OSX screenshot you posted? I am plagued by the same issue.

Comment: @stevejb: Nope :(. It was a little better in VMWare, but still terrible. I ended up reverting to iTerm + ssh'ing into a VirtualBox machine that runs Emacs in a TTY/no GUI. It works pretty well -- here's my [silly provisioned setup](https://github.com/jmdeldin/box). GUI Emacs would be great though because DocView is super handy.

Comment: @jmdeldin thank you for the to your setup. It seems like a very reasonable approach. I just tried installing (a few minutes ago) [Infinality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html) and it seems to have improved things quite a bit. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a high resolution 27" monitor using the NVidia binary driver.

Comment: @stevejb: Awesome -- can you post a screenshot of Emacs running in your VM?

Comment: http://steve.planetbarr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/emacs_nice_fonts.png

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely prefer the current rendering, but if you like bolder, more blurry and fonts with colors on the edges, you should disable hinting, enable subpixel rendering and keep anti-aliasing enabled. A better solution would be to just use bolder fonts, but this would rather look crisp as printed in a book and not blurry. So it depends on what you mean with "smooth".

Read more on hinting (and see a nice comparison screenshot) on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting

Comment: Thanks for your hints (har har)! I adjusted my [~/.fonts.conf](https://gist.github.com/2890528), and it's better, especially with a bold font (sadly, Emacs doesn't like bold Inconsolata or Monaco). I wish it was more 1:1 with OS X, but it's a definite improvement. It's still ugly over X11, but switching to VMWare and Unity mode lets me run the "native" Emacs window without using X11 (it's much more reliable than VBox's seamless mode).

Answer (score 2):

After running the `./configure script` in the `emacs` folder, you might see something like this near the end of the output:

```
Where should the build process find the source code?    .
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             yes
      (Using Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          LUCID
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 yes
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng12
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use cairo?                                   no
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
  Does Emacs support sound?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               no
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes -lglibc (inotify)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    yes -lacl
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                no
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  no
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   no
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                no
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
  Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
```

Notice that it says no after `-lfreetype` and `-lxft`. If you install these libraries, `emacs` should use the proper font:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev
```

You can do the same thing with most of the other no's that you get. After you have installed libraries that you want, run `./configure` again and then `make` and `sudo make install`.